# Use matched value in case construct in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm pattern matching on the data constructor of a record, and I have the following chunk of code:

```
colorFor shape = 
  case material shape of
    ColorMaterial -> material shape
    -- etc.
```

The problem is this: `material` is a nontrivial method, and I'd like to not recompute it in the case statement. I know I could do something like:

```
colorFor shape = 
  let m = material shape
  in case m of
    ColorMaterial -> m
```

or

```
colorFor shape = 
  case material shape of
    ColorMaterial r g b -> ColorMaterial r g b
```

But I couldn't help but think there must be some way to retrieve the matched value in a pattern match. This also comes up for function definitions, where I'd like to match on the data constructor for some argument without completely unpacking it.

FYI: I'm new to Haskell, and if there are better ways of doing what I'm doing I'm very open to suggestion. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for "[as patterns](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html)":

```
data SomeDataType = ColorMaterial Int Int Int
                  | BlandMaterial

colorFor shape = 
  case material shape of
    res@(ColorMaterial _ _ _) -> res
    -- etc.
```

Comment: The potential issue here is that you would have to define way more "as patterns", one for every datatype you would like to return immediately rather than having one let.

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for, but Phyx's argument concerning how it's just translated to a `let` anyway has convinced me to keep it as it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure there's any "better" way to do it than

```
colorFor shape =  
  let m = material shape 
  in case m of 
      ColorMaterial -> m
```

In particular looking at what ghc does with the "as pattern" that Thomas suggested running ghc -ddump-ds shows that ghc just makes this into a let after desugaring

```
 Main.colorFor :: forall t_ac9. t_ac9 -> Main.SomeDataType
 [LclId]
 Main.colorFor =
   \ (@ t_ac9) ->
     letrec {
       colorFor_ac8 :: t_ac9 -> Main.SomeDataType
       [LclId]
       colorFor_ac8 =
         \ (shape_aby :: t_ac9) ->
           **let** {
             res_abz :: Main.SomeDataType
             [LclId]
             **res_abz** =
               GHC.Err.undefined @ (t_ac9 -> Main.SomeDataType) shape_aby } in
           let {
             fail_dcV :: GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld -> Main.SomeDataType
             [LclId]
             fail_dcV =
               \ (ds_dcW :: GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld) ->
                 Control.Exception.Base.patError
                   @ Main.SomeDataType "Test.hs:(5,3)-(6,36)|case" } in
           case res_abz of wild_B1 {
             __DEFAULT -> fail_dcV GHC.Prim.realWorld#;
             **Main.ColorMaterial ds_dcS ds_dcT ds_dcU -> res_abz**
           }; } in
     colorFor_ac8
```

It's rather verbose but i've marked the important parts with **<>**. The undefined is ofcourse because "material" doesn't exist in my code and i needed it there to compile. So the As-Pattern is only better when there's just one of it. Any more and you're better off making one let yourself. Less typing and looks better imho.

This seems to hold in general too:

```
data SomeDataType = ColorMaterial Int Int Int 
                  | BlandMaterial 
                  | NoMaterial

colorFor shape =  
  case undefined shape of 
    res@(ColorMaterial _ _ _) -> res 
    foo@BlandMaterial         -> foo
```

just introduces another let, and is already more typing than just having one let.

```
 Main.colorFor :: forall t_ace. t_ace -> Main.SomeDataType
 [LclId]
 Main.colorFor =
   \ (@ t_ace) ->
     letrec {
       colorFor_acd :: t_ace -> Main.SomeDataType
       [LclId]
       colorFor_acd =
         \ (shape_abz :: t_ace) ->
           let {
             **res_abA** :: Main.SomeDataType
             [LclId]
             **res_abA** =
               GHC.Err.undefined @ (t_ace -> Main.SomeDataType) shape_abz } in
           let {
             fail_dd0 :: GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld -> Main.SomeDataType
             [LclId]
             fail_dd0 =
               \ (ds_dd1 :: GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld) ->
                 Control.Exception.Base.patError
                   @ Main.SomeDataType "Test.hs:(6,3)-(8,36)|case" } in
           **let** {
             foo_abB :: Main.SomeDataType
             [LclId]
             **foo_abB** = res_abA } in
           case res_abA of wild_B1 {
             __DEFAULT -> fail_dd0 GHC.Prim.realWorld#;
             Main.ColorMaterial ds_dcX ds_dcY ds_dcZ -> res_abA;
             Main.BlandMaterial -> foo_abB
           }; } in
     colorFor_acd
```